# Change In Proper Length After Acceleration?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration

A train has length $L$ whilst at rest in a station - this is a proper length. It undergoes a homogenous acceleration (each particle of the train moves in exactly the same way) until it reaches a velocity $v$, after which it continues at this velocity.

[image: Spacetime Diagram]

Now it seems as though the length in the station frame remains $L$, but the proper length of the train must then be $\gamma_v L$, as the length $L$ is in a frame in which it moves at velocity $v$.

So it seems we have two different proper lengths.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The world lines for the front and back of train are the same, apart from a horizontal displacement. They begin with a separation of L, so must retain this.

Comment: A closely related idea: [Bell's spaceship paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_spaceship_paradox). In this case, the "rope" would be the train, and the "spaceships" would be its hypothetical end-points. The problem also seems to be deeply linked to what it means for an object to be [rigid in special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rigidity).

Comment: Note that an ordinary train would not move like this. It would undergo a motion in which the front and back had different proper acceleration, in such a way as to preserve the proper length.

Comment: @AndrewSteane: Surely this must depend on what forces are applied to the various parts of the train, no?

Comment: @WillO yes that is quite correct. Hence the word "ordinary"---I have in mind the kind of motion in which the acceleration is not so abrupt that the internal stresses can't keep up.

Comment: The train is intended as a metaphor for an accelerating frame. I was just using the standard pedagogy in SR (stations, trains etc.) to make for easier reading.

Comment: The wider context of the question is a desire to understand how the differences between frames actually arise via the acceleration process. The usual approach is to start with two frames in relative motion and establish the different properties from there. The question has proved fruitful in that regard.

Comment: @AndrewSteane:  Well of course ordinary trains are not ordinarily accelerated to relativistic speeds.  I'm not sure we can know what combination of forces would be "ordinary" in a situation that has pretty much never arisen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original frame, the train of course (as you've correctly argued) retains its length $L$.

In the frame of the moving train, the front of the train started moving before the rear did, so the train was stretched.

If you define the proper length of the train to be its length in its own frame, then the proper length has increased.

Of course the moving train is Lorentz contracted in the lab frame, where its length (still $L$) is less than its new proper length.

Comment: So a meter stick remains a meter stick in the frame in which it has a uniform velocity.  The (longer) proper length is actually the result of a stretching process during the acceleration.

We usually talk of length contraction, but the relative shortness of the moving metre stick is actually due to an expansion!

Comment: @S.V. :  (I see that you already understand this; just stating it in a different way):  Let $A$ be the length of the train in the lab frame before it accelerates.  Let $B$ be the length of the train in the lab frame after it gets up to speed.  Let $C$ be the length of the train in its own frame after it gets up to speed.  "Lorentz contraction" means that $B$ must be less than $C$, but it doesn't tell us anything about $B$ versus $A$, which depends on the details of the acceleration.  That in turn has **nothing to do with relativity** because it can all be computed in a single frame.

Comment: Continuing --- relativity is about comparing the way things look in one frame with the way they look in another (so for example the length of the "moving" train in two different frames, which I called $B$ and $C$, are related by the Lorentz contraction, which means we're doing relativity).  But the comparison of $A$ with $B$ all takes place in a single frame, so there's no relativity involved --- it's all just about the elementary math and logic of figuring out where each end of the train is at time $t$, given initial conditions and acceleration paths.